# A module not found error in a python-selenium project

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, global-variables, modulenotfounderror

I am actually new to this, I was assigned to do a selenium project where there's already a bunch of code written i need to run and test it out. But when i run i keep getting this error. I have given the code and the error below! can any one help me with it.

```
import unittest
from common.common import minutes_seconds, cleanup_screenshots
from common.selenium_wrappers import *
import HTMLTestRunner
from Email import *
from Email import send_email
import common.global_vars
from common.common import *
import sys
import common.common
```

its, the code and

```
  from common.common import minutes_seconds, cleanup_screenshots
  File "c:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\Insights\common\common.py", line 16, in <module>
    import global_vars
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_vars'
```

this is the error i am getting.
Can anyone tell me what to do ? And there is a file named global_vars.py in a folder named common . I tried to import it from there too but I am still getting the same error.

I tried

```
import common.global_vars
from common.common import *
import sys
import common.common
```